# How to save data from react component to a file

Tags: node.js

I want to save the content of my form from a react component to a file in the form of JSON which I want to read by another react component.

How can I achieve this.

I am trying to use node to accomplish this.
when I add the below code on the component the project compiles successfully but on the browser I am seeing the error saying that fs.writeFile is not a function.

I think this may not work and I am doing something which is not right.
Any idea?

I am using web pack.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const content = JSON.stringify(user);

fs.writeFile("../tmp/UserDetails.json", content, 'utf8', function (err) {
    return console.log("done");
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: The title should contain a summary, not your entire problem statement. Please add a description of your problem and what remedies you have tried to your question.

Comment: Not a function on browser? does that mean you are using server code on the client side? Besides, you also have a missing parenthesis on your script and unreachable code after the `return console.log("done");`